# Generating MultivaluedMap parameter definition using annotations with swagger-gradle-plugin (OAS3)

Tags: java, swagger-codegen, swagger-3.0, multi-value-dictionary

We had next code generated by previous plugin with version OAS2:

```json
{
          "description" : "parameters",
          "in" : "body",
          "name" : "body",
          "required" : false,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "additionalProperties" : {
              "items" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "type" : "array"
            }
          }
        },
```

After switching to OAS3 we found out that the next definition (inside a method of a resource) is not generating parameter at all:

```
@Parameter(description = "parameters") @NotNull MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters
```

Trying to do some workaround with additionalProperties, but still can't see generated parameter:

```
 @Parameter(description = "paremeters", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "object"),
additionalPropertiesSchema = @Schema(type = "string")))
@NotNull MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters
```

Is there any way to generate parameter for MultivaluedMap using annotations so it would look something like this?
[Generated parameter in swagger UI]
[image]